# Creating a calculation in an android app using a database

Tags: android

I am in the process of creating an android app using Eclipse IDE, I want to create a database in the app and when a user chooses three options an answer will be calculated using the database, Any tips on the best way to do this or is there any tutorial that could help me out? I know this is a pretty broad question but any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that you understand what we do here: first you have to code something by your own (maybe you can start by reading Android official page); second if you get stuck in a problem, you can ask here for any help, of course providing your code and your log; third in the future, you can improve this site with your knowledge. Sorry if i am rude, but this is the way you can learn something.

Comment: I have done a lot of code creating the app interface and and what i want the button widgets to do i am just having trouble sourcing information on creating a database. I didn't know you had to provide evidence of your code. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is too broad and it would really have been better if you'd have googled some related topics first. However, if you want to work with databases Google has a tutorial for you [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). I think the external storage might be more than sufficient for your problem, so you can find a tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).